# Error when trying to create a new form using Web Form for Marketers

Tags: wffm

We have a Sitecore 8.1 instance with the latest version of WFFM just installed.  Now I am trying to create a new form and I am getting the following error.  I have no idea at all what this means or how to debug or troubleshoot it.  Any ideas what could be causing this?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.]
   Sitecore.Events.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result) +1596
   Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters) +438
   Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaved(Object sender, ItemSavedEventArgs args) +311
   System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e) +0
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent(EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator) +129
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute() +266
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item) +285
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.SaveItem(Item item) +291
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.PipelineBasedItemProvider.ExecuteAndReturnResult(String pipelineName, String pipelineDomain, Func`1 pipelineArgsCreator, Func`1 fallbackResult) +81
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.PipelineBasedItemProvider.SaveItem(Item item) +230
   Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.AcceptChanges(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent) +229
   Sitecore.Forms.Shell.UI.CreateFormWizard.SaveAnalytics(FormItem form, String goalID) +571
   Sitecore.Forms.Shell.UI.CreateFormWizard.SaveForm() +741
   Sitecore.Forms.Shell.UI.CreateFormWizard.OnNext(Object sender, EventArgs formEventArgs) +66

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +76
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +193
   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +35
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CallMethod(Type type, Object obj, String methodName, Boolean includeNonPublic, Boolean includeInherited, Object[] parameters) +37
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CallMethod(Object obj, String methodName, Boolean includeNonPublic, Boolean includeInherited, Object[] parameters) +66
   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Component.HandleMessage(Message message) +298
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.ClientEventCommand.SendEventMessage() +219
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.ClientEventCommand.Execute(CommandContext context) +16
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.RaiseEvent() +146
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +593
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +113
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4297

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34274
```

Comment: Is this an upgraded instance ? Also is it CMS only mode or not ?

Comment: Yes, this is an upgraded instance.  I have no idea what "CMS only mode" means.

Comment: Do you have xDB enabled on your Sitecore instance ?

Comment: Yes, we have xDB enabled.

Comment: Looks like some kind of miss configuration of WFFM for me :)

Comment: It looks like some **item:saved** event handler is throwing an exception, that is being hidden.
So have you tried to find some more info in the Sitecore log files for that? 
Maybe it's just some custom event handler that is failing?

Comment: Corey, was this an upgraded instance? And if so, did you follow ALL of the WFFM marketers upgrade steps?  If not an upgrade, disregard this comment completely. =)